# What does make a question in German (not) rhetorical?

Tags: rhetoric, question

Are there specific terms or grammatical structures that make a question including a statement rhetorical?

For example. The statement and question is

> Ist das römische Reich an seiner eigenen Grösse zugrunde gegangen?

How would you formulate this using german terms/grammar to denote/imply to a non historian that the statement

- is true
- is wrong (simple negation to *is true* not allowed ;)
- is highly uncertain (i take this case also as not everyone picks up a question immediately as rhetorical but as a real question)

I mean especially more subtly ways (single terms/grammar shifting the meaning completely, no use of subordinate clauses) as

> Wir wissen doch alle, dass das röm. Reich ... gegangen ist, oder nicht?

Your questions should differ in as less terms/grammar as possible ;)

**Can all rhetorical german questions literally be translated without loosing their meaning or are there examples bound in any way to german grammar/terms as in English?**

Answer (score 5):

> Ist das römische Reich nicht an seiner eigenen Größe zugrunde gegangen?

communicates "is true".

> Ist das römische Reich etwa an seiner eigenen Größe zugrunde gegangen?

communicates "is wrong". "Nicht" and "Etwa" can also be placed directly after "Ist".

With a different intonation, the first sentence could also be used by someone who speculates that the statement is true, but is not sure, and asks for confirmation.

Comment: Although the placement of "nicht"/"etwa" makes a difference in meaning: "Ist etwa das Römische Reich...?" takes the Roman Empire as an example in a discussion about *any subject*, introducing the topic of the Roman Empire's demise as an example to make a point. "Ist das Römische Reich etwa...?" would more often be invoked in a discussion about the Roman Empire itself (although it could also be used in the same fashion as its counterpart).

Comment: +1 some side questoins: What does `Ist das röm. Reich etwa nicht ... gegangen` express then? :) ... Is there way to make the three cases without basing it on intonation/pronounciation for written language? Im not totally convinced by the *etwa - is wrong*, this would more state the uncertain/hypothetical case to me? Or is this clear cut in German? Imo your examples are prob. correct for native speaker. But maybe a bit too subtly to differ all 3 cases surely? ;)

Comment: Your side question: `Ist das römische Reich etwa nicht an seiner eigenen Größe zugrunde gegangen?` applies the "probably true" connotation to the negated statement, i.e., the statement `The Roman empire did not perish because of its size` is probably true.

Comment: @Oguk No, the "etwa" applies a "probably false" connotation. So, the question `Ist das römische Reich etwa nicht an seiner eigenen Größe zugrunde gegangen?` implies that the statement `The Roman empire did not perish because of its size` is probably false.

Comment: @Hauser The "etwa nicht" is similar to the "nicht", but stronger. The "etwa" conveys a mood of surprise (`"Nein, ich trinke heute keinen Alkohol." -- "Bist du etwa schwanger?!"`). This is the same mood that is used in the rhetorical question, i.e., "I'd be surprised if the statement is true". The "etwa" is not used for the uncertain/hypothetical case, `Wäre es vielleicht möglich, dass das römische Reich an seine Größe zugrunde gegangen ist?`

Comment: @Georg: Errr, yeah, of course, you are right. "etwa" applies the "probably false" connotation, as noted in the answer, and the same applies to a negated statement. I think I copied the connotation from the wrong statement in the answer after having thought it through...

Comment: I think an important/common one is missing: "tatsächlich". `Ist das röm. Reich tatsächlich ... zugrunde gegangen?` strongly communicates a "no".

Answer (score 1):

A common combination is *question word* + `denn` as in

> **Wozu** mach' ich mir **denn** die Mühe?

Another possibility is *question word* + `wohl`

> **Weshalb** bin ich **wohl** hierher gekommen?

But note, that it highly depends on the intonation and on what the actual question aims at.

Answer (score 1):

Stefan Walter already gave quite adequate answers to your questions 1 and 2. So I will aim to answer your third one:

> Ist das römische Reich wirklich an seiner Größe zugrunde gegangen?

This construction type of questions I stole from boring gonzo documentaries, where it is used to imply that something stunningly unlikely is about to be "revealed" to the audience. That's the moment I switch off the telly.